# XP for Immolators using Burns Twice as Bright

Tags: dungeon-world, experience-points

I'm a GM of a party that includes an [Immolator](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3269630/dwdotcom/Immolator-V1.pdf). The player has expressed interest in Burns Twice as Bright with his next level up. In order to be prepared, I want to know how I should grant him XP when using this move. The moves are as follows:

> Burns Twice As Bright
>   When you **channel the flames of fate,** you may treat a missed roll as a 7-9 or a
>   7-9 result as a 10+. This may be a roll you or another character has made. Tell the
>   GM something you’ve lost; an emotion, a memory or some innate piece of your
>   being. You may not use this move again until you’ve used *Burns Half As Long.*
>
> Burns Half As Long
>   *You gain this move when you gain Burns Twice as Bright.*
>   When you **sacrifice a victory to the flames of fate,** treat any roll of 10+ as a miss.

As I read it, XP could be granted at either of the following times, **but not both**:
1) A fail is rolled; mark XP. The Immolator uses Burns Twice As Bright to convert it to a hit.
OR
2) The Immolator uses Burns Half as Long to recharge. Mark XP for the now failed roll.

Personally, I like the second option, as that provides delayed gratification of XP, and offers more incentive to use Burns Half As Long.
However, since this is an "official" class from Koebel and LaTorra, I'd like to award XP in the same manner that they would. Unfortunately, I can't find any such ruling that confirms or counters my own ideas.

Is there any "official" rule of how to handle XP for Immolators using these moves?

Comment: Is this class released for free? If so a link to the playbook and any related pages might help us deduce if the information is present. That said, welcome to RPG.SE!

Comment: I suggest asking this question on the DW Tavern on Google Plus, linking in Adam as he frequently contributes to discussions there. As this mechanic is unique to the Immolator and nowhere referenced in the rulebook you won't get a definitive answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those wondering, I decided on to go with the second option,

> The Immolator uses *Burns Half as Long* to recharge. Mark XP for the now
>   failed roll.

Using *Burns Twice As Bright* converts a miss to a partial hit. Players do not mark XP for partial hits; why would the effect of this move make it otherwise? They are choosing to use the move and, as such, forfeit the XP in order to gain the effect of a partial hit.

Additionally, while an Immolator can convert **any** miss to a partial hit, they must forfeit **their own** hit when using *Burns Half As Long*. This means that while the Immolator will always gain XP for using *Burns Half As Long*, they always deny other players of XP when using *Burns Twice As Bright* on their behalf. With this in mind, the other players at the table have the right to refuse *Burns Twice As Bright* made on their behalf. In such a case, the move is not used, and play continues without interference.

This is my opinion; others may interpret the rules in a different way. Feel free to discuss how this is handled in your games, or make suggestions for improvement, in the comments.